# Field's Formik bag empty when nested in third party component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm using Formik's `Field` component to render an input like this:

```
<Formik 
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  render={formProps => (
    <Form>
      <Field name="lastName" render={({ field, form }) => (
        <input {...field} placeholder="lastName" />
      )} />
    </Form>
)} />
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0w97oqjjl) that illustrates the issue.  You'll see if you swap the product column definition with the one that just renders the product as a string rather than use a Formik input, it works fine.

In the code above, Formik seems to be "automagically" determining the Formik bag `form` object in the `Field`'s `render` function.

This has worked without issue until I integrated my `Field` into a third party library, in my case, rendering it in a cell of an agGrid table.  When I do this, I get *TypeError: this.props.formik.registerField is not a function* browser console errors.  Debugging this error, I see the following in Formik's compiled code:

```
FieldInner.prototype.componentDidMount = function () {
  this.props.formik.registerField(this.props.name, this);
};
```

When I inspect `this.props.formik` which should be my Formik bag, it's an empty object.  This is the same object I see when I put my break point in the `Field`'s `render` function.  When I inspect this object for instances of my `Field` outside of agGrid, it is the fully populated Formik bag including `initialValue` props, `registerField` function, etc.

**Why is Formik not properly retrieving the Formik bag `form` object when my `Field` is nested in an agGrid table cell and how can I address this issue?**

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a version of React >=16? If so it looks like AgGridReact doesn't support the new version of the context API that Formik is using behind the scenes.

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react/issues/131

Either wait for AgGridReact to release a new version, or consider downgrading to a version of React <16 so Formik falls back to the old context api.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  I wonder if there is any way to force Formik to use the old context API...

Comment: Formik just uses this lib to polyfill https://github.com/jamiebuilds/create-react-context ... doesn't look there's anyway to make it fallback aside from using a different react version ...

Comment: agGrid supposedly handled this with version 20.0.0 distributed 2 weeks ago.  https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react/issues/131.  It's the version used in my CodeSandbox which still doesn't work. A teammate has been working on this and had the following comment: `While the Context API is able to pass in correct FormProp ref, when it renders, the prop becomes undefined somewhere within the render chain. I was able to get the input rendering but it was uncontrolled. I read an agGrid Github issue that agGrid internally doesn't use React, but rather native JS which may be why this is happening.`